# Python error only applies to one set of similar things?

Tags: python

I am making jeopardy for a school project, (in python) and I have a few variables:

```
contestants = ['Alex Trebek', 'George Jerone', 'Bradford Bradford', 'Dwight Shrute']
categories = ['4 letter words', 'Nature','Stupid answers','Common bonds']
```

and:

```
 def categoryChoose():
  global category1
  global category2
  global category3
  global category4
  global category5

  category1 = random.choice(categories)
  categories.remove(category1)
  category2 = random.choice(categories)
  categories.remove(category2)
  category3 = random.choice(categories)
  categories.remove(category3)
  category4 = random.choice(categories)
  categories.remove(category4)
  category5 = random.choice(categories)
```

and:

```
def contestantChoose():
  global contestant1
  global contestant2
 
  contestant1 = random.choice(contestants)
  contestants.remove(contestant1)
  contestant2 = random.choice(contestants)
```

I know that I called the functions right, and am wondering why I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 46, in <module>
    contestantAnnounce()
  File "main.py", line 42, in contestantAnnounce
    categoryAnnounce()
  File "main.py", line 35, in categoryAnnounce
    print('The categories are: '+category1+', '+category2)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "tuple") to str
```

The odd thing is that the error only applies to the categories, and not the contestants. Could someone please explain?

Here is the full code:

```
 import random
    contestant1 = ()
    contestant2 = ()
    category1 = ()
    category2 = ()
    category3 = ()
    category4 = ()
    category5 = ()
    contestants = ['Alex Trebek', 'George Jerone', 'Bradford Bradford', 'Dwight Shrute']
    categories = ['4 letter words', 'Nature','Stupid answers','Common bonds']
    def contestantChoose():
      global contestant1
      global contestant2
     
      contestant1 = random.choice(contestants)
      contestants.remove(contestant1)
      contestant2 = random.choice(contestants)
    def categoryChoose():
      global category1
      global category2
      global category3
      global category4
      global category5
    
      category1 = random.choice(categories)
      categories.remove(category1)
      category2 = random.choice(categories)
      categories.remove(category2)
      category3 = random.choice(categories)
      categories.remove(category3)
      category4 = random.choice(categories)
      categories.remove(category4)
      category5 = random.choice(categories)

    def categoryAnnounce():
      print('The categories are: '+category1+', '+category2)
    def contestantAnnounce():
      contestantChoose()
      print ('This is Jeopardy!')
      print ('With Alex Trebek!')
      print ('Alex: Thank you. Tonight we have: '+contestant1+', and '+contestant2+'!')
      print ('Now we move on to the categories. Player chooses first!')
      categoryAnnounce()
    
    
      
    contestantAnnounce()
```

EDIT: I have solved it. I swapped the +s in the print with ,s and that fixed it.

Comment: just realised there is only 4 catagory options my god im dumb

Comment: I just added in one more item to the catagory list, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: `catagory1, catagory2, catagory3` etc. is a list which is longing to be born. Why not simply `category = list(random.sample(categories,5))`? And why the global variables rather than a simple `return`?

Comment: @JohnColeman because I have no idea how to do that

Comment: You can shuffle the list and use indicies directly, so don't remove anything or make new variables

Comment: Fair enough -- but hopefully you will learn such things sooner rather than later. Your code is very repetitious and [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) (DRY) is one of the most important principles in coding, with a good choice of data structures one of the ways to achieve that goal.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you never called `catagoryChoose()`, and you've defaulted the categories to empty tuples rather than empty strings